# Argparse not recognizing arguments

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, argparse, subparsers

I am having some trouble with argparse. My goal is to have the user select one and only one option (-a, -b, -c, etc.) and then the arguments for that option. I'm using subparsers to do this:

```
parser_iq = subparsers.add_parser('iq', help='iq help')
parser_iq.add_argument("-iq", "--index_query", nargs="+", action=required_length(1,6),type=organize_args, help="Choose an index to query for. Start-date, end-date,  "\
           "csv, json, stdout are all optional")
```

This is just one of the subparsers I plan to have.

**Problem**: When running this in the command line:

```
python3.6 main.py iq "index_name_here"
```

I get the error that "index_name_here" is unrecognized. I am parsing it like this:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I found some problems similar to mine, but they were passing in sys.argv into parse_args(), which was their issue.

How can I make it so that argparse will recognize the arguments passed? Also, is there a way to have only one option passed in at a time? For example:

Correct:

```
main.py option1 arg1 arg2
```

Wrong:

```
main.py option1 option2 arg1 arg2
```

Thank you!

Comment: `python3.6 main.py iq -iq "index_name_here"`.  The first `iq` identifies the subparser.  The `-iq` flags its argument.

Comment: Are you defining the `required_length` Action class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the value like `python3.6 main.py -iq "index_name_here"` (i.e., use `-iq`, not `iq`).

As far as making mutually exclusive arguments, subparsers is, from what I understand, the way to go, but I can't give much in the way of guidance on how to proceed on that.

Edit:

In response to your comment, does the following work:

`python3.6 main.py iq -iq "index_name_here"`

?

Comment: thanks for the help! When I try running with -iq, it gives me this error: 

 error: invalid choice: 'log4j-*' (choose from 'iq')

Comment: Yes, iq -iq works! I didn't think about that at all, and it doesn't make much sense to me. Do you know why it runs like this?

Comment: @helloworld95 When you pass `iq`, python knows to invoke the `parser_iq` parser (because that's the first argument you pass to `add_parser`). This parser has an argument that can be changed by passing an `-iq` or `--index_query` flag along with its associated argument. The documentation isn't the best, but see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: According to the docs, its not required to specify both the parser and argument (iq and -iq).

>>> parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
>>> parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')

>>> parser.parse_args(['a', '12'])
Namespace(bar=12, foo=False)

It seems like I'm following the doc, but its still not working as I'd like it to.

Comment: That `bar` argument is a `positional`.  Your `-iq` is a flagged (`optionals`) argument.  The distinction is fundamental to how `argparse` works.  The `subparsers` argument is actually a specialized `positional`.